# Calculating change in period in terms of ellipticity

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have an ellipsoid that changes into a sphere. I want to calculate $\delta p / p_{initial}$ in terms of the eccentricity $e$.

I'm given that the moment of inertia of an ellipsoid is approximately $2/5 Ma^2$. I know that the volume of an ellipsoid is $\frac{4 \pi}{3}a^2b$, and eccentricity is $e = c / a$, where $a$ is the longest semimajor axis of the ellipsoid, and $b$ is the shortest. $c$ is the distance from the ellipsoid's center to the focus. I know that the final ellipticity of the sphere is zero (since c=0).

Given this information, I am trying to calculate the change in period over the initial period in terms of $e$. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: The period of what motion?

Comment: The rotation of the object.

Comment: Around what axis?

Comment: An general ellipsoid has three different semi-major axis lengths. You seem to be talking about a spheroid.

Comment: Given the equation for the moment of inertia being only in a, rotation would be about the short axis of an oblate spheroid.

Answer (score 1):

The angular momentum, given as $L = I \omega$, is a conserved quantity. Given more context, it might not be the case, but if so then you are stuck. Therefore:

$$\frac{d\tau}{\tau} = \frac{d(Ma^2)}{Ma^2}$$

Now you say the spheroid is changing. In what way is it changing? Is M constant? Is the volume constant? Or is it that a is constant?